# Expected identifier or '(' in Xcode

Tags: objective-c

This is my first Mac app, and I'm erroring out in simple code.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSButton *AddHostsButton;

NSFileManager *fileman;

fileman = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([*fileman fileExistsAtPath:@"/private/etc/hosts" ] == YES)
NSLog @"Hosts exists";

else NSLog @"Hosts not found";


@end
```

Answer (score 2):

In Obj-C, strings are written `@"like this"`, not `"like that"`.

And you need to put your code in some method body.

Comment: Expected an Objective-C directive after '@' comes back after adding the @.

Comment: *cough* You need to give me some more info, noob here.

Comment: `[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"/private/etc/hosts"]` -- is this what you have?

Comment: lose the parenthesis around the string.  Objective-c has named parameters with brackets so you don't need parenthesis.

Comment: I did NSFileManager *fileman and used that variable instead, but now there's load of the errors I've mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Your code belongs a) inside an `@implementation` block rather than an `@interface` block, and it needs to be part of a method definition, not just hanging out in the open like you've shown. It should look something like this:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/private/etc/hosts"] == YES)
        NSLog (@"Hosts exists");
    else
        NSLog (@"Hosts not found");
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Class method '+fileExistsAtPath not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: @user1222053 I never claimed that your code was correct -- I just put it into a form that should at least make some sense. As for that particular error, it's because `fileExistsAtPath:` is an instance method instead of a class method. I'll fix that in the code above, but you really owe it to yourself to learn more of the language and learn to use the documentation. There's nothing wrong with being new, but that shouldn't stop you from being able to figure many of these errors out.

Answer (score 1):

While Caleb and Cyrille have identified specific problems, the overall problem is that you aren't writing Objective-C code.  That is pseudo-code at best.

You need to start with a beginner's guide to Objective-C -- there are many -- and learn the language.

(Not meant as an insult -- we were all where you are at one time!)